# ZRAID1 pool size bigger than expected

Tags: raid, zfs, software-raid, raid5, raidz

I have 3x 4TB drives for a ZRAID1 config (single parity drive)

After running

```
zpool create data zraid1 sdb sdc sdd
```

I have a volume that's 10.9T in size, which is what I would expect from a stripe configuration, not a RAID5 configuration. zpool status claims it is a raidz1-0 config (the 0 makes sense, this being the only pool on this machine).

Why is my size not 7.2T ?

---

Figured it out: *zpool list* shows total of the pool, not the resultant volume size. *df -h* shows that correctly as 7.2T.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zpool list` shows the size of the pool, which is the size of all the disks.
`zfs list` will show the usable file systems sizes in the pool.