# Why is my RAIDZ2 pool larger than the expected size calculation?

Tags: zfs, raidz

I'm building a RAIDZ2 ZFS system, using Ubuntu 13.10 as a base system, and zfsonlinux's packages, having 6 disks dedicated to the pool data and a couple of SSD partitions to do ZIL log and L2ARC cache. My HDDs are all 2.0 TiB (in fact: slightly less than 2.0 TiB) drives.

Yet, once the pool was created, `zpool list` unexpectedly reports a pool having 10.9 TiB size, 1.93 MiB allocated, and 10.9 TiB free.  How is it getting nearly 11 TiB free in a RAIDZ2 having a total of 12.0 TiB of disks? I was expecting to have a mere 8.0 TiB of free space (4.0 TiB being allocated to parity).

Oh, this is apparently a very similar question to [ZRAID1 pool size bigger than expected](https://serverfault.com/questions/548372/zraid1-pool-size-bigger-than-expected), but about RAIDZ2 instead of RAIDZ... I'll post this anyway, in case anyone cares about RAIDZ2 for their searches.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that each drive is 1.82TiB. That, times 6 = 10.9TiB. I suppose zpool reports the total physical space available for filesystem labour (ie: data + parity) as opposed to just the space available for user data without the parity factored in.

In fact, the "duplicate question" has a perfectly good answer already, quoted here (added dashes for clarity):

> `zpool list` - shows the size of the pool, which is the size of all the
>   disks.
>
> `zfs list` - shows the usable file systems sizes in the
>   pool.

PS. Maybe we should have a "raidz2" tag.

Comment: *(don't use raidz or raidz2!!)*

Comment: Because: http://nex7.blogspot.com/2013/03/readme1st.html - There are serious compromises to using RAIDZ(1,2,3) in your ZFS arrays. Performance, expandability, complexity...

Comment: @ewwhite the article you mentioned did include some limitations performance-wise for building a "raidz(2)", it also included decent advices for someone building a "raidz(2)". There is also compromises in building mirror vdevs, and of course compromises in raidz alternative: soft/hard raid.