# Why is the size of a zfs filesystem after sending it to a different pool different?

Tags: solaris, zfs, zpool

I've move a zfs filesystem from a pool made of a bunch or mirror vdevs to another pool made of two raidz1s with the following command

```
# zfs send -R pool/project@moving | zfs recv tank/project
```

As far as I understood the manpage, '-R' moves all the metadata as well, including the compression algorithm etc., which is exactly what I see:

```
# zfs get compression pool/project
NAME            PROPERTY     VALUE     SOURCE
pool/project    compression  lz4       local
# zfs get compression tank/project
NAME            PROPERTY     VALUE     SOURCE
tank/project    compression  lz4       received
```

So why is the the filesystem on the target pool (tank) over 20% bigger than on the source pool (pool). It's a diference of almost 6TB and I'm curious, where I lost that.

Comment: Show the filesystem sizes, please... `zfs list`

Comment: Oh, you're right, 'zfs list' show actually the same size. But why does 'zpool list' show this:     

# zpool list
NAME     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
pool    36.2T  27.9T  8.33T         -    77%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
tank    36.2T  34.7T  1.57T         -    95%  1.00x  ONLINE  -

Comment: Curious. Why are you moving to RAIDZ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZFS mirrors are usually much better than RAIDZ(1/2/3) for a variety of reasons (performance, expansion, *sanity*). This confusion about displayed size is one of them.

Please see: [Why is my RAIDZ2 pool larger than the expected size calculation?](https://serverfault.com/questions/564365/why-is-my-raidz2-pool-larger-than-the-expected-size-calculation)